# Protected Pages in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

I am currently using MediaWiki as a documentation website, with login authenticated by LDAP.

However, we have hit a snag.  Certain pages contain sensitive information.  For example links that say "click here to log in". I would like to be able to protect certain pages from being edited by just anyone.  I would like to allow certain groups of users (like employees) to edit those pages.

How do I set up page protection by group in MediaWiki (if it is possible)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is well-covered in the [MediaWiki docs](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MediaWiki_Administrator%27s_Handbook/Page_Protection):

Answer (score 2):

In addition the page protection options [Andy Lester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8454/andy-lester) linked to you can also setup site wide protection against account creation and anominous  editing. See [MediaWiki Manual:Preventing access](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Preventing_access)